# Unity Light Bugs in Android

Tags: unity, android, lighting

I was testing my game, so I made a build to test it on my phone.
I noticed that when I play in an android build, it is so darker than when I play in the editor or in a PC build.

It looks like this in the editor and in PC builds:
[image: editor and PC builds]

And like this in Android builds:
[image: in Android builds]

It is a Unity Bug? Or is it an error in my project?

Comment: Do you use the same quality settings for your android build?

Comment: @Zibelas There are the same both for Android and PC.

Comment: Please walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Once we van reproduce your problem in a new, empty project, we can test potential solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be that I had `No Shadows` as the Shadow Type. I thought that it won't be that dark. But what I don't know is why only happened on Android builds and not in PC builds.
Changing Shadow Type to Hard or Soft Shadows should solve the problem.

Or

Leave Shadow Type in `No Shadows` and in the affected GameObjects disable both `Cast Shadows` and `Recieve Shadows` options under `Lightning` in `Mesh Renderer`